# Finding column with nearest higher value in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the index (or the name) of the column with the closest value to another column. More precisely, I have a dataset that look like:

```
data <- data.frame(cum_1 = c(1,2), 
           cum_2 = c(2,3),
           cum_3 = c(3,4),
           median = c(1, 2.2))
```

And I'm trying to come up with a function telling me which of the cum_i column gives me the nearest number **above** the associated median value. With the dataset provided above for instance, the function would tell me that `cum_1` provides it for the first row, and `cum_2` does it in the second row. (Or in index notation).

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max.col` for a vectorised option :

```
max.col(data[-ncol(data)] - data$median >= 0, ties.method = 'first')
#[1] 1 2
```

---

`data[-ncol(data)]` removes the last column (`median`) and subtracts each of these columns with `data$median` to get :

```
data[-ncol(data)] - data$median
#  cum_1 cum_2 cum_3
#1   0.0   1.0   2.0
#2  -0.2   0.8   1.8
```

We compare this output with `>= 0` to get `TRUE`/`FALSE` values

```
data[-ncol(data)] - data$median >= 0

#     cum_1 cum_2 cum_3
#[1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Since `TRUE > FALSE` we can use `max.col` to get column index of maximum value in each row. In case, if there are more than 1 value which are `TRUE` we specify `ties.method = 'first` to get the first index.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this but here's a base R start:

```r
apply(data, 1, function(x) {
    val <- x[-length(x)] - x[length(x)]; which.min(replace(val, val < 0, NA))})
#[1] 1 2
```

Explanations:

1. `apply(data, 1, function(x) ...)` applies the function to every row (since `MARGIN = 1`).
2. The function calculates `val` for every row as the values from all columns except the last `x[-length(x)]` minus the value in the last column `x[length(x)]` (the `median` column). The function then returns the index of the row vector (i.e. the index of the column) with the closest but higher value to the median value. We get the "closest but higher" value by replacing all closest but smaller values with `NA`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems to work but I have a hard time applying it to my actual dataset as I don't really understand how you set ```median``` as being the value to which the comparisons are made

Comment: Hi @cynk34; I have added some explanations that hopefully will help. Please take a look.

Comment: I made it work thanks to your explanations, thanks a lot!